# dispatchGesture в android блокирует нажатие кнопки

Tags: android, kotlin

Пишу автокликер. Реализован класс AccessibilityService Есть оверлей в другом сервисе чтобы никак не соприкасались. Все хорошо но в момент эмуляции клика dispatchGesture блокирует собственно мой тап по кнопке оверлея можно ли как то это обойти?

```
 fun playClick() {
        if (!working) return
        //CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            var mode: Int = scenario!!.configClick.modeWork
            var protect: Boolean = scenario!!.configClick.protect
            var interval =
                if (!protect) scenario!!.configClick.intervalClick else scenario!!.configClick.intervalClick //пока так
            //var v: View = scenario!!.views[indexAction!!]!!.view
           // var point = getRealCoordClick(v)

            // v.visibility = View.GONE
            var clScenario: ScenarioClick = scenario!!.lstScenrioClick[indexAction!!]
            var point = Point(abs(clScenario.posX), abs(clScenario.posY))
            val swipePath = Path()
            var duration = scenario!!.configClick.intervalClick
            swipePath.moveTo(point.x.toFloat(), point.y.toFloat())
            //swipePath.lineTo(150f, point.y.toFloat())
            val gestureBuilder = GestureDescription.Builder()
            gestureBuilder.addStroke(StrokeDescription(swipePath, 0, 40))
            dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), object : GestureResultCallback() {
                override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                    indexAction = indexAction!! + 1
                    if (!isComplatedCycle()) {
                        isComplateWork(mode, interval, false)
                    } else {
                        indexAction = 1
                        isComplateWork(mode, interval, true)
                    }

                }

                override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                    L.i("OnCanceled was invoke")
                    indexAction = indexAction!! + 1
                    if (!isComplatedCycle()) {
                        isComplateWork(mode, interval, false)
                    } else {
                        indexAction = 1
                        isComplateWork(mode, interval, true)
                    }
                }
            }, null)
        //}
    }
```

В принципе код особо не надо проблему я описал это 100% из-за этого, пробовал помещать в другой поток но ничего не получилось. Что интересно в других подобных программах все решено и прекрасно работает, но кроме как увеличения времени задержки вообще ничего в голову не приходит, но это не особо помогает. Вот кнопка на оверлее если что

```
playBtn!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            if (scenario == null) return@OnClickListener
            if(scenario!!.views.size < 2) return@OnClickListener
            if (!working) {
                working = true
                setStopStartRes(R.drawable.baseline_pause_24)
                playStart()
            } else {
                stopWork()

               // autoClickService!!.stopWork()
            }
        })
```